# WPF XAML namespace issue when reusing Working Window and helper class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF Window class that uses a local (in the same namespace) class for closing the Window from a ViewModel.  I copied this class from another project, where it works just fine, and changed the namespaces appropriately.  I am getting a designer and compile error with VS that the class does not exist in the namespace.  Here is my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MOABIMTools.Views.CreateTypesView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:MOABIMTools"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MOABIMTools.Views"
    local:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}"
    Title="BIM Parameter Maintenance" Height="500" Width="1000">
```

And here is the DialogCloser class:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MOABIMTools.Views
{
    public static class DialogCloser
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "DialogResult",
                typeof(bool?),
                typeof(DialogCloser),
                new PropertyMetadata(DialogResultChanged));

        private static void DialogResultChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = d as Window;
            if (window != null)
                window.DialogResult = e.NewValue as bool?;
        }
        public static void SetDialogResult(Window target, bool? value)
        {
            target.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I have cleaned and rebuilt, reset the namespace reference in the xaml by copy/ paste, shut down VS and restarted, and changed from the xc namesapce to the local and nothing has helped.  I'm just not seeing the error.  But I get the blue squiggly line under the DialogCloser binding line in the Xaml file as well as a compile error:

```
Error       The name "DialogCloser" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MOABIMTools.Views".
```

I feel like the mistake must be something simple, as both the window and the DialogCloser class come from another working project.  But I am not seeing the problem.

Comment: I copied the DialogCloser class into a new WPF application and was able to reference it from the MainWindow.xaml without any issues. I got the "The name "DialogCloser" does not exist in the namespace" error to begin with but that went away after building the project. Check properties of the DialogCloser class file in solution exploer. Make sure it's set to compile.

Comment: Interesting . . . the class is set to compile and the window is set to Page.  I might delete it and re create it and see if that helps.

Comment: @PaulGibson this is the usual setting for a page and a class

Comment: @Wearwolf I think I have it solved.  This project is a class library "Add-In" for revit, and in my post build events I sign and copy the dll into the right place for Revit to find it.  I have had Revit open and so the post build even throws an error, and the Xaml error is thrown after the post build error (?).  Closing Revit allowed it to compile without error (though I still get the designer blue line error).  Seems like the build order is causing some confusion for the designer.

Comment: I can compile, and intelisense will let me retype the line xc: and prompts me with DialogCloser.DialogResult etc. but the designer error remains so I cant see the window in design mode.  I have cleaned, rebuilt, restarted, etc all with no luck getting rid of the blue squiggly error in the designer view.  This is frustrating . . .

Comment: When you initialize your components in the codebehind of the view, was DialogResult initialized first?

Comment: @PaulGibson Are you moving for copying the build output "into the right place for Revit to find it"? I think the designer does something with the build output so if you aren't leaving a copy in the original output folder it might mess up the designer.

Comment: @Wearwolf  Great point to keep in mind . . . I copy rather than move, but did not know that.

Comment: @Xcalibur37 In my view model DialogCloser is initialized in the constructor.  I first create the ViewModel, then I create the window, and in the window constructor set the datacontext.  So I think the order of construction and initialization is appropriate.

Comment: Do you set the DataContext before or after you call InitializeComponent?

Comment: @Xcalibur37 That is set after the InitializeComponent call.

Comment: Switch the order and see if your property now exists. You usually set the DataContext first, especially in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

`DialogCloser` is in `namespace MOABIMTools.Views`, but in your xaml you set `xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:MOABIMTools"` and then call it with `xc:DialogCloser.DialogResult`.

I think what you need to change is to replace

```
xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:MOABIMTools"
```

to

```
xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:MOABIMTools.Views"
```

the reason that you did not get error during design, maybe because it is using the old compiled objects. Try rebuild everything.

Comment: This is in fact what I have.  I have also tried moving DialogCloser into views and calling it with xmlns:local with the same result (just trying to switch things around to see if something changes).  Intelisense knows that DialogCloser is in the namespace, as it prompts with it once I type xc: . . . . (or local: if I have it there) but the blue line persists.  At this point I can compile and run, but can't see the window in designer mode.  So not a huge problem, but an inconvenience.

Comment: OK, got it. One thing that you should try: add `GetDialogResult` in your `DialogCloser`. Designer might have problem reading the value because you don't have the getter.